# Galera load balancing with wsrep_dirty_reads=On; Do I need 2 load balancers for write and read?

Tags: mysql, load-balancing, galera

I am trying to set up cross-region Galera setup, where DC1 is a master and the rest is slave. Similar setup (but with just 2 DCs) is mentioned here:
http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/weightedquorum.html#weighted-quorum-for-a-primary-and-secondary-site-scenario

```
DC1:
  node1: pc.weight = 2
  node2: pc.weight = 2

DC2:
  node3: pc.weight = 0
  node4: pc.weight = 0

DC3:
  node5: pc.weight = 0
  node6: pc.weight = 0
```

In one of the failure scenarios there might be a situation where.

`node5` becomes `non-primary`, whilst `node6` stays `primary`. 
In this case in DC3 I would like `writes` to go to the node6, whilst reads could go to any of the nodes (preferably node6).

Another situation might be where both `node5` and `node6` become `non-primary` in which case I would like read-only queries to be sent to both nodes, but "write" queries to be rejected.

I can't see any easy way of achieving the above with just one load balancer. Shall I have 2 load balancers, one for reads, one for writes?

In write load balancer node shall be removed from LB when it's in non-primary state.
In read load balancer node shall be removed if for e.g. read query fails or perhaps simply if it's not reachable on port 3306.

What would be the reliable solution for the above problem?

Comment: Your goals are unclear.  Answers to these may help clarify:  If all nodes are alive and well, where should writes go?  If DC1 goes down, what should happen to writes?  What is the latency between the DCs?

Comment: My goal is to have central location in DC1 and use DC2, DC3 for reads and non-critical writes. I am OK with the fact that if DC1 is down then there are no writes possible anywhere, however it shall be still possible to read "dirty" data.
Latency between DCs is ~150-250ms, different parts of the world.
The goal is to "emulate" standard master<>slave approach with added benefit that I can write to slave (in my case DC2, DC3). Those writes for Galera are faster than if you would write to remote-Master, because Galera only takes the RTT hit when transaction gets committed.

Comment: Is there a problem with allowing writes everywhere at all times?

Comment: That would be ideal, but then I lose the resilience of the DC1 in case network goes away, since it would have to be dependent on DC2/DC3.